# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql.so'

Tags: php, ubuntu, terminal, command

When I type `php -v` on the command line, I get the following error. 
I tried reinstalling php, but there is no change in the error.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: you can install pdo_mysql.so extension and put into the php extension directory. in higher version of php comes with this extension install by default. which version of php are you using?

Comment: I'm using PHP7. How to install pdo_mysql.so?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to do:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Comment: The error message doesn't say that it doesn't found library, the error message says there is an undefined symbol in it. Which means, the pdo_mysql.so file exists, but wants to use a `pdo_parser_param` variable defined somewhere out of it (probably in the php core), but it can't found. Simply said, the library in incompatible. Next to that, the OP is using php7 (which is also visible on his screenshot), and not php5 as you mentioned.